# C# SOAP WebService - mapping input class fields to xml namespaces

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

So this is a bit long to explain. I'm creating a SOAP Webservice and I have been given a specific XML structure that the input needs to fit (i.e. I cannot change what the input XML looks like, my service has to accept the one I've been given).

That XML would look something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:a="someurl"
    xmlns:b="anotherurl"
>
    <a:WS_Input>
        <b:ListOfThings>
            <b:Request>
                <b:Field></b:Field>
                <b:AnotherField></b:AnotherField>
            </b:Request>
        </b:ListOfThings>
    </a:WS_Input>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For this I created this C# code:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Input
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Namespace = "anotherurl")]
    public ListOfThings ListOfThings { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class ListOfThings
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Namespace = "anotherurl")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class Request
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Namespace = "anotherurl")]
    public string Field { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2, Namespace = "anotherurl")]
    public string AnotherField { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 3, Namespace = "anotherurl")]
}
```

Here I'm trying to map all fields to the "b" namespace. However, the xml this actually generates (and expects) is this one:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:a="someurl"
    xmlns:b="anotherurl"
    xmlns:ccc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.C#.Project.Root.Namespace"
>
    <a:WS_Input>
        <b:ListOfThings>
            <ccc:Request>
                <ccc:Field></ccc:Field>
                <ccc:AnotherField></ccc:AnotherField>
            </ccc:Request>
        </b:ListOfThings>
    </a:WS_Input>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that "ListOfThings" correctly maps to the namespace "b", but the rest of the fields are mapped to a new namespace (ccc) that seems like an example url.

What am I missing here?